# 301 redirect with regular expression - special case

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This topic is far to abstract for me and I fear I will never really understand how to create the right pattern.

I do have 1500++ URLs which I need to redirect with a 301. This is far to much to do manually, so there MUST be a solution.

The website contains URLs like:

somedomain.tld/somepath/

somedomain.tld/somepath/somefile.ext

somedomain.tld/somepath/somepath/text-0123456

somedomain.tld/somepath/somepath/some-more-text-0120123

somedomain.tld/somepath/somepath/numbers-1234-7654321

What I need to redirect are the last 3 types of URL. The new target should look almost the same, but without the last numbers and the last stroke.

IE:

OLD: somedomain.tld/somepath/somepath/text-0123456

NEW: somedomain.tld/somepath/somepath/text

OLD: somedomain.tld/somepath/somepath/some-more-text-0120123

NEW: somedomain.tld/somepath/somepath/some-more-text

OLD: somedomain.tld/somepath/somepath/numbers-1234-7654321

NEW: somedomain.tld/somepath/somepath/numbers-1234

Saying it in words the redirect should select all URLs ending with a "-" AND a 7 digits number, and redirect them to the same URL without that "-" and without that 7 digits number.

Thanks in advance for Your kind support!
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

This can definitely be solved by a regex based rule. Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)-[0-9]{7}$ /$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}s ^(.*):(443(s)|\d+s)$
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)-[0-9]{7}$ http%3://%1/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

will take care of redirection, keeping same protocol and possible GET parameters...